# Postgresql import from SQL Server - how to auto-generate sequences

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, sequence

As the title states I'm switching from SQL Server to Postgresql via SQL dump. The tables and views have been migrated correctly, alas the `IDENTITY` columns have not been properly converted into `SEQUENCEs`.

In short, is there a way to auto-generate or script the generation of those sequences using the highest integer value in the ID column?

Thanks, I'm looking forward to any pointers and suggestions, and sorry if this question has already been answered elsewhere!

Julian

P.S. I'm running Postgresql 9.3.6 on Debian Wheezy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CREATE table you can use bigserial/serial type

```
CREATE TABLE xx (
 id  serial,
 data text
);
```

if you need to create sequence then 
CREATE SEQUENCE serial START 1;

"Simple" way to import data from MSSQL is following
CREATE TABLE and replace IDENTITY with serial
Import all data. If you dont import id values, Postgresql replaces them with with new values. Example

```
INSERT into xx (data) VALUES ('test') ;
```

This creates new id for  row

```
 INSERT into xx (id, data) VALUES (1, 'test') ;
```

this one does not.
So import data with id and run

```
 select setval('xx_id_seq', max(id)) FROM xx
```

xx_id_seq is default naming convention where *xx* is table name *id* is column and seq id for sequence ( in my system pgadmin3 creates table with that logic)

If you want to automate whole process you need to write lot of code which reads INFORMATION_SCHEMA and does dynamic SQL , but i assume that it is not the question.

For more information see manual

sequences see : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createsequence.html

manipulating sequnces see: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-sequence.html

datatypes see: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype.html

Comment: thank you, `select setval('xx_id_seq', max(id)) FROM xx`  was what I was looking for. and, yea, I know there's gonna be a lot of scripting ahead ;)